# How to integrate Xcode with GitHub?

Tags: xcode, github

How would it be possible to integrate Xcode with GitHub?

Comment: Duplicate. Searching for 'xcode github' leads to the post below.

Comment: Well, the OP said gitHub, not git. I don't know about now but back when this was posted you had to do all sort of voodoo to get Xcode to work with an external repo like gitHub (http://www.mindthe.net/devices/2011/04/28/12-steps-to-using-github-with-xcode-4/).

Comment: I agree with Julian, why is this marked duplicate?  Xcode has an inbuilt git mechanism, but how that can be connected to github is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

A lot has happened in the world of Xcode & Git/GitHub since the original question and answers.

See [this article](http://www.elastichead.me/2013/01/github-and-xcode.html) re setting up a GitHub remote repository in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

think I found the Xcode way to push a existing project to GitHub or any other remote repository!

### **Preconditions**

I assume that you have a project created by Xcode 4 with a local git repository.
You created an empty remote git repository (I call it RemoteRepository in in the following example)

### **Push it to remote**

1. Open the Organizer in Xcode an go to the Repositories tab
2. At first click on Remotes and then on "Add Remote"

[image]

3. Enter a Remote Name and the Location of your remote repository and
   click on create

[image]

4. Then select your project and open File -> Source Control -> Push ...

[image]

5. Select your remote repository and wait until it is connectable! Look
   for the Create in the brackets.

[image]

6. Now your old project is published to GitHub

[image]

Answer (score 1):

People I know use the [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) to get the tools.  This includes a tool that lets you open the Git GUI from the current folder in the finder.

I am no aware of a plug-in for Xcode.  [Here](http://shanesbrain.net/2008/7/9/using-xcode-with-git) are some guidelines for setting up your Git to work better with Xcode projects.